# Reusing a resource manager template when DNS details are present

Tags: azure

I have a working resource manager group consisting of a Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine, network interface, public IP address and a storage account. And I have created a template from this group of resources.

When I try to deploy this group of resources, it throws an error that the DNS entry is already in use

How do I clear out the DNS?

Here is the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "DnsRecordInUse",
    "message": "DNS record <my groupname>.<my location>cloudapp.azure.com is already used by another public IP.",
    "details": []
  }
}
```

I am trying to create a template of a group of resources so I can quickly deploy a copy and then change the DNS (IP), details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else is using that address you are out of luck. Use uniqueString method to get a different value if you are building a CI system tag them and destroy them.

Reference 
Pets versus Cattle
http://cloudscaling.com/blog/cloud-computing/the-history-of-pets-vs-cattle/